# Significant difference detection on a stream of data

Tags: statistical-significance, online-algorithms

Let's there are 2 groups of user. Based on their query I return some search results to them (p1,p2,p3). The search results could vary based on either the group that user belongs to or some user specific parameter. I want to measure, whether the search results to the users are significantly different to each other or not for a given query (let's say when there is difference of more than 7 results out of first 10 results).

Are there any online learning algorithm/test to do this?

Here is what i am planning so far, group all the requests by groupid, query. Calculate the frequency distribution of search results by groupid for a given query. Measure how different are the frequency distributions (open question [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/619544/significantly-different-frequency-distribution-for-categorical-data)). Are there other techniques this can be achieved? What are the pitfals to be aware of for example what if there is a skew in number of users lying in group1 vs group2. What if there are n groups instead of just 2.

Literature suggestion are also welcome.